# Why do windows updates make linux run slower (clearing CMOS fixes it)

Tags: linux, windows, performance, windows-update, firmware

I dual boot: I write code in Linux (this problem comes up in both Arch and Debian 10), and I play games in Windows 10.  My computer is built around a Ryzen Threadripper 2950, it has 128GB of RAM.  On paper, it's no slouch.

I have noticed that my co-workers can complete certain operations in 10 minutes that take me 30 minutes, even though on paper, their machines are "slower".  At first I thought this was a filesystem-related thing because these tasks usually start with `npm install` or `docker build`.  I've seen the problem on both ext4 and btrfs though, so I'm giving up on the idea that it's a bug in my filesystem.

About three months ago I started writing down the times of certain tasks and noticed that it's not just slow.  It's slow **and getting slower**.  Then I noticed that clearing CMOS restored it to it's previous (snappy) speed.  A few days ago, I noticed a significant performance drop which started just after I spent the weekend playing games in Windows.  I believe updates were installed at some point.

The app in question was `vim`.  It was so slow that the keystrokes were entering the buffer out of order.  I would type "container" and I would see "cotannrie".  Not thinking about the cmos-fix, I profiled the slow part like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12216578

I failed to identify a problematic plugin, but eventually remembered the cmos-fix.  After clearing cmos, things were running smoothly again.  Then, for grins, I ran a similar profile.  Here is a screenshot of a diff of the before and after vim profiles:

[diff of profile output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nblzq.png)

The column on the left is how many times that line of vimscript was called during the profiling session, the column in the middle is its average execution time.  Clearing motherboard CMOS caused somewhere between a 2x and 10x speedup--which was enough for me to get back to work.  But what surprises me is that the speedup seems to be more or less evenly distributed across operations.  Even in simple things like assigning variables.

I can only replicate this once every few months, but next time I'd like to collect more useful before/after details.  So my question is: **what should my next steps be to narrow in on this issue, and what data should I collect to convince whoever's fault it is that it's a real thing?**

My current theory is that it has something to do with windows update.  I believe that the updater does this:

- set the system firmware to boot the windows EFI partition
- install updates
- reboot
- instead of fixing the firmware to be back where I left it, keep it pointed at windows

Every time I install a fresh Linux, it works for about a month, and then a windows update comes and clobbers it.  (But I can still make it boot by hitting F11 at boot time and selecting the right partition).  The boot issues may not be related, but they're evidence that Windows doesn't clean up after itself when it finishes installing an update.  So the question is, what *else* is it failing to clean up, and how can I find evidence of it?

Comment: Have you updated your linux kernel , what agesa version are you using , is your bios updated as  well? How are you measuring your docker build times? What storage solution are you using ssd , have you invoked trim and or using  samsung magician on windows

Comment: I'm currently using Kernel 4.19.160-2 (Debian 10), but when I first noticed this I was using 5.4.something (Arch).  I switched while hoping that the problem would go away.  And yes, updating my BIOS was the first thing I did.  It didn't appear to have any effect (but it's hard to say, since it takes a while to recur).  I measured our docker build times by building my company's product and seeing how many seconds elapsed (this would be bandwidth sensitive)--but the vim slowdown doesn't appear to be filesystem dependent.  I'll look into trim...

Comment: This doesnt make any sense.  Windows and its updates cannot affect the BIOS or Linux.  Most probably this is just a bug or configuration issue in Linux.  I highly suspect if you stopped running Windows, the same problem will still occur.

Comment: I'll keep a closer eye on it now that I have a quantitative measure, but I think that the performance only degrades if I boot into Windows, install updates, and boot back into Linux.  If i only boot Linux for several months consecutively the situation remains stable.

Comment: @Keltari Actually when you say that Windows cannot affect the BIOS you're not correct. When I had some issues with Summer/Winter time settings I found out that Windows has the bad habit of writing into the BIOS, the Linux in dual boot was not able to switch properly because of that.

Comment: @MatrixManAtYrService Does the slow down happen on partial builds or also on the full clean builds? If a clean build takes always the same time and a partial build slows down there might be an issue with the file timestamps. The compiler might not be able to correctly asses what's new and build more than needed.

Comment: I like where you're head's at, but the profiled code in the screenshot is vimscript, which is interpreted, so I don't think it's a partial build thing.  All I can say is that I reboot from Windows, post update, into Linux and it's slow, then I clear cmos and boot to Linux, do the same thing, and it's fast.  Some other variable could be at play, causing it to load differently, but I'm not sure what that might be.  I'll come up with a test suite and schedule it to run daily so that next time it gets worse I have a paper trail.

Comment: Also, re: BIOS--this is a UEFI system.  It was possible for configs to bleed over via BIOS, as FluidCode pointed out. I believe that with UEFI it's, uh, more possible: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/windows-uefi-firmware-update-platform

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that utilities like `sysbench` fail to measure the performance decrease, but that it was easy to spot while using `vim`, so I wrote a [benchmark script](https://github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/cmoslow/blob/ff9ff448db326bfeb974489101638dd0bd654d0a/benchmarks/benchmark#L115) which opens a file in `vim`, scrolls through it the slow way (jjjj...), and keeps track of how long it takes.

I was only aiming to get a consistent baseline so that when the next windows update comes along, I have something to compare to, but the numbers wouldn't sit still.  After [much floundering](https://gist.github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/3ad332e68907abfa998241aee38a6771) I discovered that the speed of test execution is either 10s or 40s, and it depends on whether I reboot from windows into linux, or whether I power off from windows, and power on into linux.

**On a reboot, the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti "remembers" something about how it was configured by the previous operating system.**  Whatever that is, it's the hidden variable that was upsetting my performance baseline, and it gets forgotten if you power down between operating systems.

My benchmarks consistently completed in under 10s after installing the proprietary nvidia drivers in linux and then rebooting twice (it was still at 40s after the first reboot because it was remembering a bogus config from an earlier boot).

My current theory is that `npm` was problematic because of all those fiddly animation things they do.  `docker build` is still a mystery.

I did find evidence of weird efi-related changes that only occurred when I let windows boot  (like the contents of my efi partition changing, or the /dev/nvmeXn1p1 disks changing their value of X) but I don't currently know if they're related to my performance problem.

As for Windows Updates.  I think that being prompted to go into uefi settings on a first boot after the clear was enough of a deviation in my routine that I consistently missed the "press F11 to select boot" time window--meaning that every time I cleared CMOS I also booted first to Windows, soaked up the graphics driver goodness, and then rebooted into Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced it has to do with Windows updates.

I have two dual boot machines where I boot Linux from UEFI USB drives and there's a Windows 10 in an HDD. Whenever I use the option "Restart" from within Windows, I get back into the Windows System after reboot. If I use the option "Shut Down", I get back to Windows some seconds after I turn on the computer.

The only way for me to be able to press the UEFI Boot Device Selector (F11, etc.) or even get into SETUP (delete, etc.) is to physically detach the SATA connector to the Windows HDD. Then I can reconfigure boot options, but as soon as I plugin any updated Windows 10 HDD, the SETUP gets reconfigured to put Windows Boot Manager as the first boot option back. This happens in more than one motherboard with more than one copy/version of Windows 10.

Sometimes wiping up the power (removing power cords and waiting a long time - or clearing up CMOS if you wish) "fixes" this behaviour.

So while this is not directly related to Windows Updates per se, it seems to me that some recent Windows 10 updates are taking over the memory (RAM) and even other storages (BIOS/UEFI caches, etc.)

That is my theory from my experience. I'm sorry I couldn't comment because of low reputation.